# RGB Colors in TikZ and conversion with ghost script to PNG

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, ghostscript, png

Since a few days I am trying to find a solution for the folowing problem:
I am creating a Tikz picture with a simple rectangele and fill the rectange with a special RGB color. The code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[color={rgb:red,50;green,5;blue,5}](0.0,0.0)--(0.0,20.0)--(15.0,20.0)--(15.0,0.0)--(0.0,0.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Then I create a PNG from this Pdf file with a Shell Skript:

`gs -r200x200 -sDEVICE=png16 -sOutputFile=test.png -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE test.pdf`

At last I read the output image with  Java and read the RGB Color of  a pixel inside the rectangle.
The resulting color values have alwys a big difference to the value I have set in TikZ. I think the problem is somewhere in ghost script.
I would be happy of any ideas to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 4):

You have to define the color something like this

```
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{.5,.05,.05}
```

One more possibility is to use `RGB` where you have to give numbers from 0 to 255.

```
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{128,15,15}
```

This needs the package `xcolor` (which is loaded by `tikz` in this case).

Then your tikz code becomes

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{.5,.05,.05}
%\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{128,15,15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[color=mycolor](0.0,0.0)--(0.0,20.0)--(15.0,20.0)--(15.0,0.0)--(0.0,0.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, now it works. Cant believe that this was the problem.

Comment: @Rua_de_Janeiro: In that case you may  upvote theanswer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accept it (by clicking on the checkmark). This will add some reputation points to those who answered and to you. This the tradition followed here in TeX.SX.