# How to define a color that matches inserted PNG

Tags: color, png

I am trying to use cbox and have the colors equal to the colors on the inserted figure. I opened the figure using the windows paint program and used the color picker to determine the rgb values of each bar. However, the values when used in latex do not give me the same color as shown below for the "Approach" bar in brown. The "Idle" bar also looks to be darker.

How can I fix this? Below is an MWE as well as the png files.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\Cbox}[1]{{\color{#1}\rule{2ex}{2ex}}} % added <<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\title{test}
\author{test}%

\date{January 2022}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\subfloat{
\hspace{0.1cm} Left Hand {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,height=0.02\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{segmentation-l.png}}}

\subfloat{
Right Hand {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,height=0.02\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{segmentation-r.png}}}
\caption{\Cbox{rgb:red,0.396;green,0.435;blue,0.498} Idle \Cbox{rgb:red,0.843;green,0.733;blue,0.635} Approach}
\label{fig:qualitative}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Png files

[image]

[image]

Comment: Quick fix: You can use something like `\includegraphics[width=2ex,height=2ex,trim={0 0 95 0},clip]{segmentation-l.png}` for the grey box in the legend. Otherwise, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56984/47927

Comment: @JasperHabicht thank you! That is a simple fix. But I was hoping you could tell me how you chose 95. I read through the arguments for the trim command but still can't figure out the values I should select to crop out the other colored boxes. trim={<left> <lower> <right> <upper>} I have tried a bunch of random numbers and it has not worked.

Comment: @JasperHabicht sorry I understand the trim command now.

Comment: If you define the colors first for example using `\definecolor{mygrey}{rgb}{0.396,0.435,0.498}` and then use this defined color for the box, the colors will match. I don't know exactly how this is different, but I guess, some conversion takes place.

Comment: @JasperHabicht thank you! that worked very nicely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you use the extended color expression `rgb:red,0;green,0;blue,0` that mixes colors is a very specific way that differs from more broadly used color mixing mechanisms. (See chapter 2.3.3 "Meaning of extended color expressions" on page 16 of the [documentation of the current version of the `xcolor` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf) (v2.14) on this.)

This expression namely divides every given value by the sum of all given values. In the example of `rgb:red,0.396;green,0.435;blue,0.498` every value would therefore be divided by 0.396 + 0.435 + 0.498 = 1.329 which results is the color  `0.300, 0.327, 0.375` (with percentage values ranging from 0 to 1). But this color is obviously darker than the color `0.396,0.435,0.498`, which is the color you want to get.

You can explicity specify the divisor using `rgb,1:red,0.396;green,0.435;blue,0.498` which will result in the color `0.396,0.435,0.498`.

You can also use the macro `\definecolor` with the `rgb` or `RGB` model and define a custom color which you then use later.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{mygrayA}{RGB}{101,111,127}
\definecolor{mygrayB}{rgb}{0.396,0.435,0.498}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{gray-box.png}

\raisebox{2cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \quad%
    \textcolor{rgb:red,0.396;green,0.435;blue,0.498}{\rule{5pt}{4cm}}%
    \quad%
    %
    %  0.396 + 0.435 + 0.498 = 1.329
    %  -> 0.399 / 1.329 = 0.300
    %  -> 0.435 / 1.329 = 0.327 
    %  -> 0.498 / 1.329 = 0.375
    %
    \textcolor{rgb,1:red,0.396;green,0.435;blue,0.498}{\rule{5pt}{4cm}}%
    \quad%
    \textcolor{mygrayA}{\rule{5pt}{4cm}}%
    \quad%
    \textcolor{mygrayB}{\rule{5pt}{4cm}}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]